# Bar3 plot with seperate x,y,height and width values

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

> ***Solution posted below*** function to plot bar 3 with separate x, y values and separate width and height values
>
> **bar3(x,y,z,xWidth,yWidth)**

We are currently working on a project that allow one to visualize the area under a 3d function, f(x,y). The purpose of this is to demonstrate how the bars cut a 3d surface. Indirectly to visualize the desired integral.

**We wish to have the bars match up with the intervals of the surface grid.**
Below is a rough demonstration of the idea.

[image: example of idea]

bar3 only has input for the x-values **bar3(x,z)**, where as surf has a input for both the x and y **surf(x,y,z)**

Unfortunately this is what we are getting. **- this is because bar3 cant be in terms of x and y**

[image: gui]

**CODE:**

```
clc;
cla;
d=eval(get(handles.edtOuterUpperB,'string'));
c=eval(get(handles.edtOuterLowerB,'string'));
b=eval(get(handles.edtInnerUpperB,'string'));
a=eval(get(handles.edtInnerLowerB,'string'));

n=eval(get(handles.edtInnerInterval,'string'));
m=eval(get(handles.edtOuterInterval,'string'));

h=(b-a)/n;
k=(d-c)/m;

[x,y] = meshgrid(a:h:b, c:k:d);
f=eval(get(handles.edtFunc,'string'));
surf(x,y,f);

hold on
bar3(f,1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a user contributed function scatterbar3, which does what we want, in a different way than what bar3 uses:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1420-scatterbar3

**There was however a slight hiccup that we had to correct:**

> hold on
>
> scatterbar3(x,y,f,h);

scatterbar3 does not have separate inputs for the width and height of the bars, thus large gaps occur when the intervals do not equal one another. Demonstrated below.

[image: GUI-error]

**We thus edited the scatterbar3 function in order to take both the width and height of the bars as inputs:**

*Edited scatterbar3 function:*

```
function scatterbar3(X,Y,Z,widthx,widthy)

[r,c]=size(Z);
for j=1:r,
    for k=1:c,
        if ~isnan(Z(j,k))
            drawbar(X(j,k),Y(j,k),Z(j,k),widthx/2,widthy/2)
        end
    end
end

zlim=[min(Z(:)) max(Z(:))];
if zlim(1)>0,zlim(1)=0;end
if zlim(2)<0,zlim(2)=0;end
axis([min(X(:))-widthx max(X(:))+widthx min(Y(:))-widthy max(Y(:))+widthy zlim])
caxis([min(Z(:)) max(Z(:))])

function drawbar(x,y,z,widthx,widthy)

h(1)=patch([-widthx -widthx widthx widthx]+x,[-widthy widthy widthy -widthy]+y,[0 0 0 0],'b');
h(2)=patch(widthx.*[-1 -1 1 1]+x,widthy.*[-1 -1 -1 -1]+y,z.*[0 1 1 0],'b');
h(3)=patch(widthx.*[-1 -1 -1 -1]+x,widthy.*[-1 -1 1 1]+y,z.*[0 1 1 0],'b');
h(4)=patch([-widthx -widthx widthx widthx]+x,[-widthy widthy widthy -widthy]+y,[z z z z],'b');
h(5)=patch(widthx.*[-1 -1 1 1]+x,widthy.*[1 1 1 1]+y,z.*[0 1 1 0],'b');
h(6)=patch(widthx.*[1 1 1 1]+x,widthy.*[-1 -1 1 1]+y,z.*[0 1 1 0],'b');
set(h,'facecolor','flat','FaceVertexCData',z)
```

**Finally the working solution in action:**

> hold on
>
> scatterbar3(x,y,f,h,k);

[image: working GUI 1]

[image: working GUI 2]

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely, you will see that the `XData` and `YData` are different from the mesh to the 3D bar plot. This is because your mesh uses "real" x and y values while the bar plot uses indexes for the x and y values.

To fix this, you will want to change one or the other. For your case, the easiest one to change is going to be the surface. You can actually just omit the `x` and `y` inputs and the indexed `x` and `y` values will be used instead by default when generating the surface.

```
surf(f);
```

From the documentation for `surf`:

> `surf(Z)` creates a three-dimensional shaded surface from the z components in matrix `Z`, using `x = 1:n` and `y = 1:m`, where `[m,n] = size(Z)`. The height, `Z`, is a single-valued function defined over a geometrically rectangular grid. `Z` specifies the color data, as well as surface height, so color is proportional to surface height.

## Update

If you want to keep the non-indexed values on the x and y axes, you will want to convert the `bar3` plot instead. Unfortunately, MATLAB provides a way to specify the x axis bot *not* the y axis. You can take one of two approaches.

**Change the `XData`**

You can get the `XData` property of the resulting bar objects and change them to the data you want.

```
x = a:h:b;
y = c:k:d;

%// Anonymous function to scale things for us
scaler = @(vals)x(1) + ((vals-1) * (x(end) - x(1)) / (numel(x) - 1));

%// Create the bar plot
bars = bar3(y, f);

%// Change the XData
xdata = get(bars, 'XData');
xdata = cellfun(scaler, xdata, 'uni', 0);
set(bars, {'XData'}, xdata);
set(gca, 'xtick', x)

%// Now plot the surface
surf(x,y,f);
```

And just to demonstrate what this does:

```
x = linspace(0.5, 1.5, 5);
y = linspace(2.5, 4.5, 4);

f = rand(4,5);

scaler = @(vals)x(1) + ((vals-1) * (x(end) - x(1)) / (numel(x) - 1));
bars = bar3(y, f);


set(bars, {'XData'}, cellfun(scaler, get(bars, 'XData'), 'uni', 0))
set(gca, 'xtick', x)
axis tight
```

[image]

**Change the `XTickLabels`**

Instead of changing the *actual* data, you could simply change the values that are displayed to be what you want them to be rather than the indexed values.

```
x = a:h:b;
y = c:k:d;
labels = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%.2f', x), x, 'uni', 0);
bar3(y, f);
set(gca, 'xtick', 1:numel(x), 'xticklabels', labels);
hold on

%// Make sure to use the INDEX values for the x variable
surf(1:numel(x), y, f);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for you contribution, unfortunately because we are graphing a double integral we need to have x and y intervals with different bounds and spacing. You can see this on our GUI. We will thus require the bar3 function to use the "real" x and y values. Is this possible?

Comment: @Msegling I have updated the answer with two approaches to give you what you need.

Comment: thank you so much for your contribution, it most definitely aided in the final solution. Do have a look at what we came up with, let us know if there is anything that we could adjust.